# How to put some constraint on jquery events?

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down list box and two text fields of id values namely `user`, `datePicker1`,`datePicker2`. I have this code, which works fine for `user` :

```
$("#user").change(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller :"tasks", action : "test23")}",
      data: "userName=" + e1.find('option:selected').text(),
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
         $(".errors").append(html);
      }
   });
});
```

that is, after a user selecting from the drop-down list, I send a ajax call and append the received data's to the class of div `errors`.

But what I want actually is, after the user have have been selected from `user` div, I need to look for both `datePicker1`,`datePicker2` events by keeping `user` div event the same. Now after **both** `datePicker1`,`datePicker2` events are available I need to send a ajax call.

My html code :

`user` div element :

```
<select name="user.id" id="user" required="" class="many-to-one" >
<option value="">-Choose any User from the list</option>
<option value="1" >admin</option>
<option value="2" >anto</option>
</select>
```

`datePicker1` div element:

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" value="" id="datePicker1" />
```

`datePicker2` div element:

```
<input type="text" name="endDate" value="" id="datePicker2" />
```

### Edit:

After the user have selected values of all the three drop-down box then I can make a ajax call..So it means that I need three values from drop-down list and at the same time, a change to one field should call the ajax method provided that the other two field has already selected. Hope I'm clear on this.

How I can do this?

Can anyone help me out in this, I'm new to jquery and I got stuck with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, you want the Ajax request to be made only after the user chose an option from all there drop-downs, yes?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas : yes exactly.. But after the user have been selected from the first drop-down box, and if there is a change to second drop-down field, then I can make a ajax call..So it means that I need three values from drop-down list and at the same time, a change to one field should call the ajax method. This is the place I got confused with jquery!

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that all 3 fields were select inputs. Let me see if I can come up with a solution for text inputs.. It is more tricky though

Comment: @MattWolfe: I changed to text box rather than drop box, since I'm using jqueryUI for displaying the dates. The textbox wont work on a change event?

Comment: actually according to the jquery docs it should.. I have never had any luck using the change event for text inputs.. Perhaps with the latest jquery it works good though. Let me put this on jsfiddle and see how it works.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer with a jsfiddle link.. Try it and see if that is what you want. I'm not making the ajax call obviously but I have an alert that pops up when I would make it and when I would not make it.

Comment: @MattWolfe: thanks sir, that does the job! I made a mistake in my code, left out the `$` sign in a place, thats why it haven't worked properly before. Now it works fine.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well assuming the default values for the 3 fields are the empty string, you could do:

```
$("#user,#datePicker1,#datePicker2").change(function() {
  if ($("#user").val() != "" && $("#datePicker1").val() != "" && $("#datePicker2").val() != "") {
     //make your ajax call

   } 


});
```

This will get fired whenever any of the fields change but will only submit the values to the server if all 3 values are set..

Check this jsfiddle, it should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nFKT6/1/

Comment: have edited my question. Whether this will work on that condition given in my edited part?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what my code does.. The only thing you need to make sure of is that the default value of each field is "", eg:
<select name="user" id="user">
<option value=""></value>
..other options..
</select>

Comment: This works fine. But being the `use`r and `datePicker2` have already been selected, changing the `datePicker1` is not calling the ajax!

Comment: can you post the html code you are using for the datepicker and user fields?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var myHandler = function() {
  // Don't do anything if value is missing:
  if(!$("#user").attr("selectedIndex") 
         || !$("#datePicker1").attr("selectedIndex") 
         || !$("#datePicker1").attr("selectedIndex")) return;

   $.ajax({
      url: "${createLink(controller :"tasks", action : "test23")}",
      data: "userName=" + $("#user").find('option:selected').text() + "&date1=" 
         + $("#datePicker1").find('option:selected').text() + "&date2=" 
         + $("#datePicker2").find('option:selected').text(),
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
         $(".errors").append(html);
      }
   });
}
$("#user,#datePicker1,#datePicker2").change(myHandler);
```

Comment: use `val` for God sake! `$("#datePicker1").val()` etc'

Comment: Have edited my question. I guess your method will watch for an event only on `datePicker2`.

Comment: GDoron: tell that to the question author. Ant's: I updated it to reflect the info you added.

Comment: @Diego : This is not working as expected. I just added the `console.log` after the `if` statement. I found that all time `if` is executing and it is returning from the function.